# git stash -include-untracked и переименованные (новые) файлы

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Наделал тестовых изменений в ветке включающих переименование файлов (работаю на visual studio 2019 и git bash).
Захотелось посмотреть на состояние чистого коммита без потери текущих изменений. Так что исключил:

`git checkout`

Для этого ввёл:

`git stash -include-untracked`.

После выгрузки проекта переименованные файлы стали недоступны:

> "Элемент <> не существует в текущем каталоге проекта. Возможно, он был
> перемещён, переименован или удалён."

Вопрос: как правильно сделать так, чтобы я мог посмотреть на текущее состояние репозитория, если не хочу потерять внесённые изменения, включающие переименование (создание) файлов.
Спасибо!

Comment: `git status` ...

Comment: @Kotomi
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   Name/Name/Name.cs

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   Name1/Name1/Name1.cs
        deleted:    Name2/Name2/Name2.cs

Comment: `переименованные файлы стали недоступны` в каком смысле? Недоступны по новым именам? Это нормально, вы же смотрите на то, что было до ваших изменений, а до них й файлов имена старые

Comment: @RomanKonoval Спасибо за ответ! Нет, недоступны по старым именам.
Таким образом, я просто хотел посмотреть, что было.
Я вручную внёс изменения в project.proj в имена потерянных классов, а именно изменил папку, добавил этот proj в индекс и сделал аменд. После этого всё начало работать как ожидалось. Но мне очень не верится, что, тогда делая коммит, мой proj не был изменён из-за переименования.